# Numbers - Perform arithmetic on a section of cells

Tags: macos, numbers, iwork

I have a column of cells and I want to do `41 - (value of cell)` for each individual cell without having to go through doing it manually.

I know this seems simple but I can't think of an easy and quick way to do this. I could achieve this by coping the column and then inserting formula to the original column etc but I am only doing this as a one time action so it doesn't make sense to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first cell to apply this simple formula is A1, then enter in cell B1 the formula:
    =41-$a1
hit <kbd>return</kbd>
Then select this B1 cell, grab the little right down circle and simply drag it down your selection as far as you want to apply the same formula.

Comment: This pretty much worked for me, but I did remove the $ before the 1 making the formula =41-$a1 because I didn't want to preserve the row in this context. I then copied the column and used paste formula results so I could remove the 'working' column that I created as you suggested. Thanks. :)

Comment: Well fixed :). I just tried it and improved my answer to make the easyness of the method more clear : you don't have to use paste.

Comment: I just used paste because I didn’t really want the before and after because I was merely trying to find a quick way to reverse the mistake that I had made, and if I deleted the original column (A) it would break the formula so by copying and pasting the formula results I could disconnect it.